# Is there a way to force a MySQL select query to resolve the having clause before the where clause?

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, where-clause, having-clause

I have a somewhat complex MySQL Select query that joins multiple tables with several left/outer joins, some COUNTs and expressions in the HAVING clause, and several expressions in the WHERE clause, which is called once each time I load a web-page in my web-app, and again using AJAX from the web-page to automatically page through the data from the database every 15 seconds.  Depending on which way the user is paging, values from the table in the web-page, either the first row for backwards paging or the last row for forward paging, are sent in the AJAX call to load the previous/next page.  The query expression is created using a php HereDoc that uses variable substitutions to set values that control the WHERE and HAVING clause and sorts the return data first by the votes, and then the title and artist's name as follows:

```
WHERE ...
  AND ( ( `tracks`.`title`,  `artists`.`name` ) > ( ${title}, ${name} ) )
--   This line is not included in the initial query when the page is first created/loaded, but is
--   used in the AJAX called.

ORDER BY
  -- Total_Songs_Votes, Track_Sales, Track_Votes, Track_Listens, Tracks_Title,     Artists_Name
  3 DESC,               5 DESC,      4 DESC,      6 DESC,        `tracks`.`title`, `artists`.`name`

HAVING COUNT( `track_votes`.`id` )   <= ${votes}
   AND COUNT( `track_sales`.`id` )   <= ${sales}
   AND COUNT( `track_listens`.`id` ) <= ${listens}
```

The Select output columns are:

```
SELECT `artists`.`name`                AS artists_name,
       `tracks`.`title`                AS tracks_title,
       COUNT( `track_votes`.`id` ) +
         COUNT( `track_sales`.`id` ) +
         COUNT( `track_listens`.`id` ) AS 'total_song_votes', -- Order By column 3
       COUNT( `track_votes`.`id` )     AS 'track_votes',      -- Order By column 4
       COUNT( `track_sales`.`id` )     AS 'track_sales',      -- Order By column 5
       COUNT( `track_listens`.`id` )   AS 'track_listens'     -- Order By column 6
```

The problem is that in order control the data returned by the query the counts, above, needs to use a HAVING clause due to the COUNTs, but this is executed after the WHERE clause. So instead of 'picking up' from the item that certain total_song_votes, track_votes, track_sales, and track_listens, and then song name and artist name in the WHERE clause, the query first uses the WHERE clause that can't use the votes, so only has the title and artist's name, so eliminates too many rows before the HAVING clause in used.

**How can I force the query to perform the HAVING clause filtering in the WHERE clause?**

The output of the select query looks somewhat like the following:

```html
<table border=1>
<tr>
<td bgcolor=silver class='medium'>artists_name</td>
<td bgcolor=silver class='medium'>tracks_title</td>
<td bgcolor=silver class='medium'>total_song_votes</td>
<td bgcolor=silver class='medium'>track_votes</td>
<td bgcolor=silver class='medium'>track_sales</td>
<td bgcolor=silver class='medium'>track_listens</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>DHF</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>T Song</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>4</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>0</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>DHF</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>H Song</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>2</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>1</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>1</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>0</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>DHF</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>A Song 2</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>1</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>0</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>1</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>0</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>DHF</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>A Song 1</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>1</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>0</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>1</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>0</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>DB</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>killer song</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>1</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>1</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>0</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>0</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>DB</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>Kills it</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>0</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>0</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>0</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>0</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>DB</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>scarry song</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>0</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>0</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>0</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>0</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>TB</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>Reggae All Day</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>0</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>0</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>0</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>0</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>TB</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>Reggae Just Today</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>0</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>0</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>0</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>0</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>Howard's Band</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>test</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>0</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>0</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>0</td>
<td class='normal' valign='top'>0</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

So if the first page only showed the first two rows, then the AJAX call to retrieve the next two songs would send 'DHF', 'H Song', 2, 1, 1, 0 back to the server and the WHERE and HAVING clauses would be changed to include the following:

```
  WHERE ...
    AND ( ( `tracks`.`title`,  `artists`.`name` ) > ( "H Song", "DHF" ) )

 HAVING COUNT( `track_votes`.`id` )   <= 1
    AND COUNT( `track_sales`.`id` )   <= 1
    AND COUNT( `track_listens`.`id` ) <= 0
```

So the DHF song A Song 1 and A Song 2 would both be incorrectly eliminated.

The goal here is to retrieve the next two songs* after the last one shown on the web-page, using the voting values, the song title, and artists' name, which need to be taken in that order using the WHERE clause.  As I said, above, with the WHERE clause first only considering the song title and artist's name, then songs that have lower votes but higher titles and names are incorrectly eliminated.

- I'm using only two rows here because it is easier to show the data for this example, in the real page 10 items are displayed at a time, but that doesn't really affect anything except for where the data breaks between the pages.

Please note that I expect to have a large quantity of items returned from the query, so I'd like first have the the query correctly remove as many rows before removing the remaining rows using php logic.  Also note, that the web-page automatically re-queries the database by making AJAX cause every 15 seconds and that the same page could be displayed to multiple users but not necessarily all seeing the same data as some could be paging backwards through the data or playing a song and no longer paging at the moment, so I want this query to be very efficient and not re-query the whole database each time it is run, but rather have it pick up from after the last results for each user, independently.

***FOLLOW-UP***

Astax suggested that I enclose my query in a SELECT * FROM (...) query and then do the filtering there.

I left the HAVING clause in the inner SELECT so that it performs the voting filtering first and doesn't retrieve any more data to the outer SELECT * FROM ... then it has too.  I really don't want to have to wade through the entire dataset more than necessary.

Actually, I moved the track title and artist's name to the outer SELECT's WHERE clause, but then found that it still cause too many rows to be elminated:

```
WHERE ( ( `tracks`.`title`,  `artists`.`name` ) > ( ${title}, ${name} ) )
```

So I changed the this expression to:

```
WHERE ( ( `tracks`.`title`,  `artists`.`name` ) not in
            ( ( ${title0}, ${name0} ), ... ( ${title9}, ${name9} ) ) )
```

Where the title0, name0 through title9, $name9 variables are substituted with the ten pares of titles and names shown on the page being paged-out before the SQL query is submitted to the database engine.

The problem, however, is that if the same votes are the same over more than ten songs (one web-page of songs), then the songs from previous pages will show again and paging will stop working.

This issue makes using the votes, song titles, and artist's name insufficient as a real-world solution.  I need something else that I can use to track my page breaks that still allows changes made in the server's database to be seen without a lot of overhead in terms of temporary tables that either live on the user's device or on the server.

**Any ideas on how I can manage paging and still support dynamic data as I described?**

Thanks

Comment: The problem is that `HAVING` works on the aggregated result, and the aggregated result is generated from what's left after the `WHERE` has been applied; if you could combine them you'd no longer need to use `HAVING`. Instead, could you move everything that's in `HAVING` out from a GROUP and into dedicated columns? That way you can apply indexes to those columns and move them to your `WHERE` statement as regular filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason why `HAVING` exists is to apply some filters after `WHERE` conditions and all aggregations. So the answer is no, you can't make it run before `WHERE`.

However, you may:

- Use temporary tables. Put a result of one select into a temporary table, add more data from other selects and then run a final query.
- Use nested selects, something like `SELECT ... FROM (SELECT .... WHERE ... HAVING ....) as t WHERE ... HAVING ...`

**Update:**

You don't need to use conditions in order to implement pagination. Use `LIMIT` statement - this is what it's made for.

```
SELECT `artists`.`name`                AS artists_name,
       `tracks`.`title`                AS tracks_title,
       COUNT( `track_votes`.`id` ) +
         COUNT( `track_sales`.`id` ) +
         COUNT( `track_listens`.`id` ) AS 'total_song_votes', -- Order By column 3
       COUNT( `track_votes`.`id` )     AS 'track_votes',      -- Order By column 4
       COUNT( `track_sales`.`id` )     AS 'track_sales',      -- Order By column 5
       COUNT( `track_listens`.`id` )   AS 'track_listens'     -- Order By column 6
LIMIT {$page_size} OFFSET {$page_start}
```

Or, if you have some strongs reasons to use conditions, you can use nested query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT `artists`.`name`                AS artists_name,
       `tracks`.`title`                AS tracks_title,
       COUNT( `track_votes`.`id` ) +
         COUNT( `track_sales`.`id` ) +
         COUNT( `track_listens`.`id` ) AS 'total_song_votes', -- Order By column 3
       COUNT( `track_votes`.`id` )     AS 'track_votes',      -- Order By column 4
       COUNT( `track_sales`.`id` )     AS 'track_sales',      -- Order By column 5
       COUNT( `track_listens`.`id` )   AS 'track_listens'     -- Order By column 6
   ) AS t
WHERE (t.track_title, t.artist_name, t.total_song_votes...) > ({$title}, {$name}, {$votes}...)
LIMIT {$page_size}
```

You may still add `WHERE` to the inner query for non-groupped fields to process less data. Just use not strict conditions - `>=` or `<=` instead of `>` and `<`. Further filtering will be done in the outer select.

But I repeat again - check the output of [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) for your query. Very likely you're not saving anything by using conditions instead of LIMIT.

Comment: Thanks astax for your answer.  I want to try and stay away from too many temporary tables due to the high number of calls that this query is being used.  As to nested selects, that would work, and creates an implicit temporary table which just has be, but when I put SELECT * FROM ( ... ) around my query, I got an error.  I'll expand the question to cover this.

Comment: @HowardBrown I see what you mean. Basically you're saying that since you can't use groupped columns in expression like `(a, b) > (c, d)` in `WHERE` part, you have added them as `HAVING a>c AND b>d`. But these are not equivalent expressions. Equivalent of `(a, b) > (c, d)` is `a>c OR (a=c AND b>=d)`. Try using it in your expression in `HAVING` part.

Comment: BTW, if you're concerned about performance, maybe you should consider denormalizing your database and adding those counts into a separate table rather than calculating every time on the fly. Also look carefully into `EXPLAIN <your_query>`. I think you're not saving anything by applying `HAVING` instead of using simple `LIMIT`. All columns matching `WHERE` need to be scanned anyway to calculate those aggregates.

Comment: Sorry, there is an error in the earlier comment. The correct equivalent expression, of course, should use `>`, not `>=`. This - `a>c OR (a=c AND b>d)`

Comment: astax - thanks again.  However, I'm not quite following you when you say that I should move the (a, b) > (c, d) expression from the WHERE clause to the HAVING clause, but that it should be not be >=., it definitely shouldn't be >= because that would let the first or last item on the web-page show in the subsequent depending on the paging direction.  Adding the (a, b) > (c, d) part into the HAVING clause, I would need to include the a and c columns in my GROUP BY clause, not a problem, but then you talk about 'using simple LIMIT' ...

Comment: ... which would reduce the number of records retrieved, but when is the cut made, after the WHERE clause, which I still need for other filtering but before or after HAVING clause.  Fine, I assume after which makes more sense, but what do I do about the OFFSET.  This is what I was talking about when I was saying that I need some way to determine the breaks.  There isn't a good way to do this based on the data, as I indicated when I talked about the votes applying to more than ten consecutive rows.

Comment: Your BTW comment on the performance, is also good - thanks.  I created three summary views for the votes, sales, and listens COUNTS.  As I understand it, these are updated when the underlying table is changed, but otherwise look like static tables, so my COUNTs and GROUP-BY clauses go away in favor of LEFT OUTER JOINS on the three views and then I can move the HAVING expressions into the WHERE clause and do all of the data filtering there.  I'm still trying to understand your discussion on the (a,b)>(c,d) equivalence that I'll need to extend to include the votes, sales, and listens into.

Comment: Thanks again, but what is $page_start?

Comment: Views are not really updated when the underlying tables are changed. They are essentially hiding a subquery, which is execuded on every access to a view. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16372/when-to-use-views-in-mysql

Comment: $page_start is the offset from the beginning. Page size multiplied by page number. You need to calculate it in your JS code.

Comment: Thanks, so it is a number, being how many records to 'jump over', but what if the data change is changed before the page I'm currently moving away from, say to next page after that, and even farther away from the changed data.  If the change was a new record or a deleted record, then a simple number of records to 'jump over' would cause a record to be redisplayed or a record to be skipped over when it shouldn't have been. ...

Comment: ...   To get around these I'd need to recount the total number of record and even then, I could have a problem when the vote, sales, listen, titles, and artist's name values were changed, which wouldn't change the overall number of records, but would move the records around in the sort.  I know ... if this were easy, everyone would be doing this.

Comment: By the way, my plan for these kind of changes, was to keep moving in which ever direction the user was paging, and when the user got to the beginning or end, then show the changes that occurred in the area's of the database that they were (relatively) past. Of course if they happen to move through the changed area, then that's fine, too.  No need for any special alerts telling the user of changes. ...

Comment: ,,,   Remember, most of the navigation is automatic, so the only problem is when/if a change was made on the page where the user happens to be looking, so the code dealing those items should the user try to use one the changed item, has to verify that the user has selected a changed/deleted item and update the user about the change/deletion.

Comment: Ok, this sounds like "some strongs reasons to use conditions" :) Then subquery is your friend

Comment: Thanks for all your help on this, but I still have a question about extending the WHERE clause in the sub-query: I was using (title, name) > (${title}, ${name}), and you expanded it to include the vote, sales, and listens, but these need to be <= rather than > like the title and name, because I want the item wit the most votes, sales, and listens at the beginning of the list/pages,so as far as I know you can't combine these into the (title, name) > (${title}, ${name}) expression, so I need to have two ANDed epxressions, one for the title, name and one for votes, sales, listens. ...

Comment: ... Is there any reason to not do it this way, or should I break both of these expressions into the more conventional series of simple column and value expressions, which you were showing in an earlier comment?  If there actually is a reason, then I'd use the votes, sales, listens, title, and name columns in that order in the individual column <=/> value tests, which are all ANDed together, right?  Remember, votes, sales, and listens go down and titles and names go up as you move down the list from first page to the last.

Comment: Just use `(a, b, -c) > (d, e, -f)` if you need to reverse one column :). As for whether to use this type of comparison or simple ones - it's up to you. If you can find a way to use it, use it. If not, you can always fall back to the simple comparisons.

Comment: Thanks!  Interesting, I hadn't thought about using minus to flip the operation of the multi-column comparison.  :)

Comment: I tried the minus option and it worked perfectly, it even seems to handle when the votes, sales, and listens are all 0, which is why I started this question, because the old way that I was doing this caused the pager to recall titles and names that appeared before the last record but had values greater than the last record's and but with zeros in the votes, sales, and listens column.  All is good now, thanks!.